# Creating a repeater using BLL

Tags: asp.net, database, repeater, bll

I'm trying to create a repeater control bound with data of my database.
This should be use with a BLL.
But I don't know what I have to do.

I hope someone can help me with this..

The code I used in the page.aspx.vb is:

```
Public Function showRepeater()
    Try
        ' 1 - BLL
        Dim BLLVragenRepeater As New VraagBLL

        ' 2 - Getting all topics
        Dim alleVragenRepeater As Dataset.tblVragenDataTable
        alleVragenRepeater = BLLVragenRepeater.getVraagByTopicId(5)

        ' 3 - creating repeater and binding with data
        Dim rptRepeater As Repeater = Nothing
        rptRepeater.DataSource = BLLVragenRepeater.getVraagByTopicId(5)
        rptRepeater.DataBind()

        ' 4 - show repeater in placeholder
        plcRepeater.Controls.Add(rptRepeater)
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblFeedback.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

The code I used in the page.aspx is:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcRepeater" runat="server">
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptRepeater" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <ul>
         <li></li>
       </ul>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
 </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference your DataFields in the ItemTemplate using the [DataBinder.Eval Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa334223%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).
Something like...

```
            <ItemTemplate>      
                <ul>      
                    <li><% DataBinder.Eval(rpt.DataSource, "FieldName")%></li>      
                </ul>      
            </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your repeater with a null reference:

```
Dim rptRepeater As Repeater = Nothing
```

You shouldn't do that - remove that line and things should work as expected.

Additionally, you should be binding a *collection* to the repeater and use [data binding expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx) in order to display data in the repeater itself.

Without knowing more about your data model, I can't give you a better answer.